# Scala Actors Messaging: Ping Pong Example

Tags: scala, messaging, actor

I am new to Scala and also to Actors. So, I am little bit confused. The first task I worked with is the ping pong example.
The code looks as follows

```
class PingPong(sendTo: Actor, val name: String) extends Actor {
  def act {
   loop {
     receive {
        case x:Int =>
          println(name + " received " + x)
          Thread.sleep(500)
          if (sendTo == null)
            sender ! (x+1)
          else
            sendTo ! (x+1)
      }
    }
  }
} 

object PingPongMain extends App {
  val pong = new PingPong(null, "pong")
  val ping = new PingPong(pong, "ping")
  ping.start()
  pong.start()
  ping ! 0
}
```

Output is
ping received 0
pong received 1
...

So, how does it get evaluated?
So far, I know .start() calls act().
What happens after then?
ping ! 0 gets called. Does this mean that 0 is send to the address where ping is instantiated? Then does it call act? What if there were more than one method?
But how does pong get called? I mean how does it know where sendTo is?

Also, is it possible to do this with something like
val ping/pong = actor {} instead of with *extends Actor*?

Comment: Scala Actors are deprecated, use Akka Actors.

Answer (score 0):

- You should pass around `ActorRef`s not Actors. which are resolved from an `ActorSystem`
- Each actor only needs to define `def receive = ...` so remove the `act` and `loop` ceremony around it
- There is no need to start the actor.  It will happen automatically when you get the actorRef from the ActorSystem.
- Extend the Actor trait.  I've never seen it done another way.

Comment: But could you also explain, how the above code works?

Comment: As @Ryan said, are these Scala Actors?  Akka is the official Actor framework for Scala now.